# Importando backup do PostgreSQL para MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

Fiz um backup de um banco de dados no PostgreSQL e agora quero importa-lo para o MySQL Workbench no linux, como eu faço isso (**tranformar .backup para .sql**)?

Comment: Como você gerou o backup no PostgreSQL? Qual a especificação completa do comando utilizado?

Comment: Faz tempo que eu fiz isso, atualmente uso o MySQL porque tenho mais afinidade com esse SGBD

Comment: Se você utilizou o pg_dump com formato plain ou o pg_dumpall então precisará editar o arquivo texto gerado para adequar todos os comandos à sintaxe do MySQL. Se utilizou outro formato eu não tenho conhecimento de nenhum utilitário que faça tal conversão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o pg_dump que vem junto com o postresql, com o comando abaixo sem especificar o nome do banco de dados vai ser criado um arquivo .sql no diretório que você esta com o sql que esta no arquivo .bakcup

```
pg_restore -f database.sql database.backup
```